# module not found in node js

Tags: node.js, requirejs, relative-path

I'm working on an application with NodeJS.
I'm trying to load one js file into the another using `require()`.

My folder structure looks like:

src

- test1

- design

- reports

- components

- foo.js

- test2

- services

- bar.js

I am trying to **call foo.js from bar.js** using `require()` method.

When I do `require('test1/design/reports/components/foo.js');`
and run the app using grunt dev, I'm getting the following error:

> > Error: module "test1/design/reports/components/foo.js"
> >      not found from "(some path) test2.services.bar.js"

Can any one help to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: surely it should be `require('../../test1/design/reports/components/foo.js');`?

Comment: @tfogo I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @RAS A-0- already has, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

yeah do this:

```
require('../../test1/design/reports/components/foo.js');
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Can u plz explain how does relative path works in node.js?

Comment: in the same way as it works in your operating system