# Node server not starting up at localhost & console

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to start up my Node server:

[image: code sample]

```
PS C:\Users\PCUSER\Documents\Tuts\node-course> nodemon app.js 
[nodemon] 2.0.20 
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.* 
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json 
[nodemon] starting`node app.js index.js\`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\\Users\\PCUSER\\Tuts\\node-course\\index.js'
at Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: \[\]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
\[nodemon\] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.
\
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module not found in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994355/module-not-found-in-node-js)

Comment: Please provide code and not screenshot

Answer (score -1):

Go to your `package.json` file and check the file to set for nodemon to start

e.g.:

```json
{
  "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.